# Can we use "that", "those", in a derogative way

Tags: meaning-in-context, offensive-language, demonstrative, animacy

Do you have examples of uses of "that" "those", etc... in a derogative way.

Comment: This is a comment because I do not know the grammar. It is done with inflection, "I can't believe you wore *that* to the office." The tone says that it was an inappropriate choice.

Comment: *Those people* is sometimes used when the speaker wants to avoid naming exactly who they're talking about (maybe an ethnic minority), but still imply it.  That lets them criticize a group while not explicitly saying so.   For example, "Those people have no self-respect."

Answer (score 1):

The question seems kind of broad, but I will briefly talk about *it* and *that*.

Imagine two girls, *A* and *B*. *B* is dating a man, *C*. *A* thinks *C* is ugly and not worth dating. Normally, we don't use *that* to refer to a person. We use the personal pronouns, like *him* or *her*. But we can use *that* to suggest that a person is less than human.  I assume this is widely understood as derogatory.

> *B* shows a picture of *C* to *A*.
>   A: I can't believe you're going out with *that*.

*That* would be stressed.

Imagine further that *C* comes over to visit *A* and *B*. Upon his arrival, *A* decides that she dislikes *C* more because, in her opinion, he's dirty and disgusting. We don't normal use *it* for people. Instead, we use *he* or *she*. But *it* can be used similarly to *that* above. Imagine that *C* shakes hands with *A*. Later, *A* might say

> Ew. I can't believe *it* touched me.

*It* would be stressed.

Comment: It's not so broad, it's especially about the use of "that", "those", and small words that change the meaning subtly, but especially the ones I mentionned. It's simply open on other examples. If I use "that" + noun, is it the same?

Comment: Oh, you should provide specific examples in your post. _That+noun_ can be derogatory. I will delete this answer soon.